# incompatible types required: Class<T> found: Class<CAP#1> where T is a type-variable

Tags: java, generics

The following code:

```
public class A<T> {

    Class<T> klass;
    T instance;

    public A(T instance) {
        this.klass = instance.getClass(); // this requires an explicit cast to Class<T> to satisfy the compiler
        this.instance = instance;
    }
}
```

gives upon compilation:

```
A.java:7: error: incompatible types
             this.klass = instance.getClass();
                                           ^
required: Class<T>
found:    Class<CAP#1>
where T is a type-variable:
  T extends Object declared in class A
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
  CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ? extends Object
1 error
```

Why isn't the compiler satisfied that `instance.getClass()` will always produce `Class<T>` (since `instance` is of type `T`) and requires an explicit cast instead? Am I safe just adding the explicit cast:

```
this.klass = (Class<T>) instance.getClass();
```

... and thus silencing the compiler or is there room for run-time surprises? And if not, why can't the compiler figure that out?

Comment: I had the sample problem the problem is actually something else. The source of problem for was not extending `RoomDatabase` in my Database class.

Answer (score 11):

> Why isn't the compiler satisfied that instance.getClass() will always produce Class (since instance is of type T) and requires an explicit cast instead?

Consider this:

```
A<Object> a = new A<Object>("Foo");
```

Calling `instance.getClass()` won't return a `Class<Object>` - it will return a `Class<String>`. They're not the same thing, even though every `String` is an `Object`.

You can change the code to:

```
Class<? extends T> klass;
```

At that point it's *logically* safe, but it still requires a cast because `Object.getClass()` is just declared to return `Class<? extends |T|>` (as per [JLS section 4.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)):

> The type of a method invocation expression of `getClass` is `Class<? extends |T|>` where `T` is the class or interface searched (§15.12.1) for `getClass`.

The `|T|` part means the [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) of `T`, which in this case is just going to be `Object`.

Of course, the cast doesn't actually check anything at execution time, and you'll need `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to silence the compiler completely, but at least the code would make logical sense at that point.

Comment: `Object.getClass()` doesn't just return `Class<?>`; it returns `Class<? extends |X|>`, where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is called, which in this case would be the same as `Class<?>`